# issue with preg_replace

Tags: php

This is a simple one :)

I have this line which works great:

```
$listing['biz_description'] = preg_replace('/<!--.*?--\>/','',$listing['biz_description']);
```

What is the proper regex to remove the html entity version?

This is the entities:

```
&lt;!-- --&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just decode the html entities **if you are happy with the preg_replace regex you already have**... [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)  As @ircmaxell mentioned, using regex for html parsing can be very painfull.

```
$str = "This is a <!-- test --> of the emergency &lt;!-- broadcast --&gt; system";
$str = preg_replace('/<!--.*?--\>', '' ,html_entity_decode($str));
echo $str;
```

Comment: duh, I should have thought of this earlier lol. All the regex is doing is parsing a description field so it's not very taxing on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[NEVER use regex to parse HTML/XML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)...

An implementation with DomDocument (assuming valid xml):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml($listing['biz_description']);
removeComments($dom);
$listing['biz_description'] = $dom->saveXml();

function removeComments(DomNode $node) {
    if ($node instanceof DomComment) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    } else {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            removeComments($child);
        }
    }
}
```